# HLSL: What happens when I "squish" a 3x3 matrix into 3x2 matrix?

Tags: unity-game-engine, matrix, hlsl, shaderlab

Initially I thought it just means that the last column is simply discarded, but apparently I am getting differing results when I do such conversion as contrasted with just declaring a 3x2 matrix.

```
float3x3 TBN = float3x3(IN.tangent, IN.binormal, IN.normal);
float3x2 TB  = float3x2(IN.tangent, IN.binormal);

half2 vNormalTBN = mul(sampledNormal, (float3x2)TBN);
half2 vNormalTB  = mul(sampledNormal, TB);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm absolutely no shader expert so this is just a very wild guess and might be completely wrong! ^^

Afaik the components in the matrix are layed out column wise (vertically) and look somewhat like

```
IN.tangent.x IN.binormal.x IN.normal.x
IN.tangent.y IN.binormal.y IN.normal.y
IN.tangent.z IN.binormal.z IN.normal.z
```

and is memory wise simply stored as 9 floats in this order.

So similar when you explicitely use the `float3x2` constructor you get something like

```
IN.tangent.x IN.binormal.x
IN.tangent.y IN.binormal.y
IN.tangent.z IN.binormal.z
```

When however you simply typecast I suspect that you simply cut off the last 3 float values and force the shader to interpret this now 6 floats array as a new `float3x2` matrix which now might look like

```
IN.tangent.x  IN.binormal.x
IN.normal.x   IN.tangent.y
IN.binormal.y IN.normal.y
```

Comment: Oh, thank you for your answer, that makes sense but it is really bewildering what would be the possible use for such a mixed up matrix.

The context of my question was a reverse engineered moon shader from the Witcher 3 game as described [on the following blog here](https://astralcode.blogspot.com/2018/12/reverse-engineering-rendering-of_22.html?fbclid=IwAR0G-PbM8lpCVG56aKABtQnQYJMzMFDmn-CwFNNUwMTDVSF3NzXB-b-xun0) in the section where the world-space TBN matrix is cast into such 3x2 matrix.

Comment: I don't know as said this is just a wild guess ... and if it is true there is absolutely no use ^^ you just should not use the cast then